# Object has no method when using prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, prototype

I'm kind of a noobie in javascript, and when i try to use prototypes to extend my object, i get the following error code :

```
Object function ProcessManager() {...} has no method 'startBrowsing'
```

Here is my code. I execute this code in nodejs.

**The code**

```
function ProcessManager(){
    this.browser = new Browser();

    this.salePagesToVisit = [];
    this.salePagesCurrent = [];
    this.salePagesDone = [];

    this.categoryPagesToVisit = [];
    this.categoryPagesCurrent = [];
    this.categoryPagesDone = [];

    this.listPagesToVisit = [];
    this.listPagesCurrent = [];
    this.listPagesDone = [];

}

ProcessManager.prototype.startBrowsing = function () {
    winston.log('verbose', 'Starting scrapping Bazarchic');

}


var processManager = new ProcessManager();
ProcessManager.startBrowsing();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code sample, you're calling `startBrowsing` like it's a static method on your constructor function `ProcessManager`.

Methods added to the prototype of a constructor function are available as methods on instances. You should be calling `startBrowsing` on your *instance* of `ProcessManager`:

```
var processManager = new ProcessManager();
processManager.startBrowsing();
```

Comment: You're right ! What an awful mistake i made. Thanks